# Proving the sentence $X \lor Y {\implies}Z$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to prove that $$(\neg b \lor \neg c) {\implies} \neg a.$$

Now, acknowledging that $\lor$ is the inclusive 'or', this statement means that showing at least one of $\neg b$ or $\neg c$ is sufficient to show $\neg a.$ So, is there anything logically incorrect about using *both* $\neg b$ and $\neg c$ to show $\neg a$?

**EDIT:** I am now realizing that this question is independent of negations/contrapositives. The core of my question is: if $(X \lor Y) {\implies} Z$ and since "$\lor$" is not exclusive, then may I use $(X\land Y)$ to show $Z$?

Comment: Do you mean showing $(\neg b \to \neg a) \land (\neg c \to \neg a)$ or $(\neg b \land \neg c) \to \neg a$? The former is the correct way to go, and the latter is equivalent to $a \to (b \lor c)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I don't understand your question. I understand that the contrapositive of $a \implies (b \land c)$ is $\neg(b \land c) \implies \neg a$ which is equivalent to $(\neg b \lor \neg c) \implies \neg a$ by DeMorgan's. The statement $(\neg b \lor \neg c) \implies \neg a$ is the statement I have a question about. Now, that I think about it, this question is independent of negations/contrapositives.

Comment: Either way, for proof by cases from a disjunction $A \lor B$ to a conclusion $C$, you must show both $A \to C$ and $B\to C$ (or something to that effect) in order to actually derive $C$.

Comment: Your last sentence before the edit is ambiguous, in the way PW_246 pointed out. You need to clarify which you mean.

Comment: @PW_246 I understand what you're asking now. I meant the latter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prove $(\neg b \lor \neg c) \to \neg a$, you could also try proving proving the equivalent $a \to (b \land c)$

(I wonder if maybe that's where the $(\neg b \lor \neg c) \to \neg a$ came from in the first place?)

Anyway, proving $a \to (b \land c)$ would seem to be a little more direct: just assume $a$, and try to prove $b \land c$ ... which would merely require you to prove $b$ and $c$ individually.

Effectively, you would have to prove $a \to b$ and $a \to c$.

Now, for each of those you could prove the contrapositive .. and note that if you have $\neg b \to \neg a$ as well as $\neg c \to \neg a$, then you have shown $(\neg b \to \neg a) \land (\neg c \to \neg a)$, which is equivalent to $(\neg b \lor \neg c) \to \neg a$

So you could say that it really doesn't matter whether you try to prove $a \to (b \land c)$ or $(\neg b \lor \neg c) \to \neg a$ .. in the end, you need to prove 2 things:

1. Either $a \to b$ or  its contrapositive $\neg b \to \neg a$
2. Either $a \to c$ or  its contrapositive $\neg c \to \neg a$

And note, maybe for the one the direct proof is easier/more intuitive, but for the other one the contrapositive proof is easier to think about.

Also: note that you need to show *both* of 1 and 2. So, when you say:

> this statement [i.e. $(\neg b \lor \neg c) \to \neg a$] means that showing at least one of ¬b or ¬c is sufficient to show ¬a

you are expressing what that statement means correctly ... but in order to *prove* that statement, it is *not* sufficient to show just one of 1. and 2 ... you need to *prove* both, so that once you have that statement, anyone who has $\neg b$ can infer $\neg a$, *and* that anyone who has $\neg c$ can infer $\neg a$

Answer (score 2):

> I want to prove that $$\color{brown}{(\neg b \lor \neg c) {\implies} \neg a}.$$
>
> is there anything logically incorrect about using *both* $\neg b$ and $\neg c$ to show $\neg a$?
>
> if $\color{brown}{(X \lor Y) {\implies} Z}$ and since "$\lor$" is not exclusive, then may I use $(X\land Y)$ to show $Z$?

$$\color{brown}{(X∨Y→Z)}\tag1$$
$$(X∧Y→Z)\tag2$$

1. To be clear: your goal is simply to prove sentence $\color{brown}{(1)},$ rather than to prove that sentence $\color{brown}{(1)}$ implies sentence $(2).$
2. Observe that conditional $\color{brown}{(1)}$ has a weaker condition than the conditional $(2).$ This means that $\color{brown}{(1)}$ is a stronger sentence than $(2),$ which means that sentence $\color{brown}{(1)}$ implies sentence $(2)$ but **not vice versa**. Convince yourself that $$(X∧Y→Z)   \kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies \color{brown}{(X∨Y→Z)}$$ by considering a false $Z$ with $X$ and $Y$ having opposite truth values.
3. A few more relevant logical facts:
   \begin{align}(X→Z) ∧ (Y→Z)   \implies   &\color{brown}{(X∨Y→Z)} \\
   (X→Z) ∨ (Y→Z) \kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies &\color{brown}{(X∨Y→Z)}\\
   (X→Z) \kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies &\color{brown}{(X∨Y→Z)}.\end{align}
   Also relevant: the main condition in the middle line is equivalent to sentence $(2).$

Answer (score 2):

In order to derive the formula $(X \vee Y) \to Z$, at least two approaches come to mind:

**Approach $1$** : First, assume $X \vee Y$ is true. Then, under that assumption, derive $Z$. You are then justified in concluding *if* $X \vee Y$, *then* $Z$. The inference rule that supports this is known as *conditional proof*, and it stems from the *deduction theorem*, here applied as follows

$$ X \vee Y \vdash Z \Leftrightarrow \hspace{5pt} \vdash (X \vee Y) \to Z $$

**Approach $2$** : First, assume $X$ is true. Then, under that assumption, derive $Z$. This allows you to infer $X \to Z$ via *conditional proof*. Secondly, assume $Y$ is true. Then, under that assumption, derive $Z$. This allows you to infer $Y \to Z$ once again via *conditional proof*. Having inferred both $X \to Z$ and $Y \to Z$ separately, you are then justified in concluding $(X \vee Y) \to Z$. This last piece of reasoning is supported by the inference rule known as *conjunction introduction*, here applied as

$X \to Z, Y \to Z \vdash (X \to Z) \wedge (Y \to Z)$,

together with the following logical equivalencies

$
\begin{array}{l1}
(X \to Z) \wedge (Y \to Z) & \\
\equiv (\neg X \vee Z) \wedge (Y \to Z) & \text{Implication Rule} \\
\equiv (\neg X \vee Z) \wedge (\neg Y \vee Z) & \text{Implication Rule} \\
\equiv (\neg X \wedge \neg Y) \vee Z & \text{Distributive Law} \\
\equiv \neg (X \vee Y) \vee Z & \text{DeMorgan's Law} \\
\equiv (X \vee Y) \to Z & \text{Implication Rule}\\
\end{array}
$